# Code will not run async?

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I am trying to run the following code in a dispatch_async, but it still freezes the app. Is this intended?

```
appDel.captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        if appDel.captureSession.canAddInput(appDel.audioInput)
        {
            appDel.captureSession.addInput(appDel.audioInput)
        }
        appDel.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
```

EDIT:

Here are the dispatch queues I have tried with no success. The code at the top was placed inside each, I am just showing which I used.

```
let sessionQueue :dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("SessionQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    dispatch_async(sessionQueue, { () -> Void in

    })

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

    })

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you share your code in which you call dispatch_async?

Comment: I have added my dispatch_async pieces.